# What do you call devices which passed the test successfully?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, abbreviations

Say we have two lists (or two buckets. whatever is easier for you to imagine)

1. List of the devices under testing.
2. List of the ones which ***passed the test successfully*** and moved from list (1) to list (2).

What do you call either of these lists, especially the second one?

e.g. for the 2nd list:

- Passed Devices (but it's ambiguous what they passed).
- Devices which passed the test! (two descriptive for a title of a list)
- Passed Test Devices! (sounds wrong)...

Comment: **devices passed testing** vs. devices under testing.

Comment: atm I am doing **Devices Under Testing** & **Successfully Passed Devices**. However I was looking forward to get better alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Under review* and *Inspected* (or *Passed Inspection* if you need to be clearer).

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***"Certified Devices"***

> [certified (adj):](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certified)
>
> - having met the official requirements that are needed to do particular type of work
> - officially approved as having met a standard

For example, Apple refers to its line of refurbished products as [Apple Certified](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/apple_certified.html). Each device "is [first] fully tested...[and, as a last step] is placed into a Final QA inspection prior to being added to sellable refurbished stock."

Comment: good suggestion, however as a reader I would ask the question "What are they certified for and by whom?". such as your example, which tells the reader, these are the products which are certified by Apple and for passing refurbishment test by saying **Apple Certified Refurbished Products**

Comment: @Mehrad a certified product, as defined, in one that has met a standard or met official requirements. In this context, the requirements (or standards) are those of a test. I don't think you will find a more specific adj. that fits the context.

Comment: Absolutely the correct term.  Google UL (Underwriters Laboratories)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**Approved Devices**](http://www.fda.gov/MedicalDevices/ProductsandMedicalProcedures/DeviceApprovalsandClearances/Recently-ApprovedDevices/ucm381097.htm).

> [approve](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/approve): to consider fair, good, or right; to authorize or sanction

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with simply **tested**. And yes, this is potentially ambiguous, since it could refer to those units which were tested and failed. However, such units are usually referred to as failures or rejects, and in this context, "tested" would almost certainly be understood as shorthand for "tested and passed" or "tested and functional".

Comment: **Tested** and **untested** work for me. If you need a word for the ones that were tested and didn't pass the test, **failed** or (less formally) **fallouts**. Sometimes the acronym DUT (Device Under Test) is used for devices currently being tested.

Answer (score 0):

If the test results can be trusted, the device can now be called a *known-good component*.